# Lubuntu 18.10 LXQt desktop no user login after booting

Tags: login, password, lxqt

Interesting one. After some time of leaving ubuntu I decided to run Lubuntu again. This time 18.10. There is a new desktop called LXQt as far as I can see. MY problem; after installing it it runs straight to the desktop without  need for user login. Ok. I must say I like comfort and getting to the point of things quickly. Sadly I have installed lubuntu on a Compact flash, which I carry around. So, without wanting to be paranoid I think it would be good to protect it with a password after booting up at least.

Trying searching on key words on duckduckgo.com like "lubuntu LXQt config file" or "lubuntu change auto login" did get me nowhere. All the solutions provided are based on different desktop gui's like lightdm etc.
These desktop gui's store there config files in a different /etc directory. Why is there so much change on important functions like the desktop gui in 1 type of distribution? It creates confusion and scaring away new users...

My question; How to have a login window back in my setup for lubuntu 18.10?

Thanks in advance for all help.

update: I forgot to mention that in the 'users and groups' tool there is no selector for login screen or anything like that. Could be I overlooked something. Because I couldn't find it, I started to investigate the terminal en config file direction...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question; How to have a login window back in my setup for lubuntu 18.10?

I opened a terminal and ran

```
sudo nano /etc/sddm.conf
```

I saw:

```
[Autologin]
User=dkb
Session=Lubuntu
```

where "dkb" is my user name.

- I deleted the `User=dkb` line
- saved the file
- exited nano
- rebooted

Now I see the login screen.

**Reference:** https://github.com/sddm/sddm

---

**Edit:**

Saving changes requires "persistent" storage. If you don't have persistent storage, you'll just have to start all over again from the iso and enable persistent storage.  And you then might as well enable the password requirement for login.